# Handle click event in fragment from Acitvity, broadcasts?

Tags: java, android, android-broadcast

I have a simple scenario:
One **ViewPager** with x amount of items, each item can have 1 or 2 buttons.
The click of the button will start a new **Activity**(same for everyone) with some parameters specific to the button.

I have a adapter with hard coded fragments as **ViewPager** items and now I'm thinking about how to handle the events of the clicks on the button.

The main code for moving to another **Activity** currently exists in the **MainActivity**.

I found at least 2 ways of doing it:

1. Let the **Activity** implement a interface and send it with the adapter to the fragments and register it as a click event handler.
2. Let the fragment send a local broadcast that is then picked up by the **Activity**

I found the 2nd approach to be very simple to implement and needed less code, also does not need to send the **Activity** to several places, but is there any drawbacks to this?
And is there any good reason to go with the 1st approach?

Comment: How about sharing a view model between the activity and the fragments? I think this would be safer and simpler, because it's lifecycle aware and more contained.

Comment: hmm, do you mean that the view model should handle the click event and then trigger the Activity change in the Activity then?

Comment: It's an option, sure - especially if you're using databinding, which simplifies handling the click events. The buttons "click" through to the single shared view model instance, which forwards an event to the activity via a `LiveData`. In some ways I think it's cleaner than fragment listener interfaces and broadcasts.